# TestFlight External Beta Tester Invitation Dexterity

Tags: ios, testflight

When I use TestFlight to invite external testers to test my binary, although my external testers are divided into groups, it seems that Test Flight only allows a None or All External Testers Invitation scheme ? This means that I either have to invite all external testers to test my binary, or none. Is it possible to invite external testers to test a binary selectively by group, with TestFlight ?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have already had a previous Beta then you are right the option after approval is to invite all the previous testers. The way round this is to edit the testers on the build and remove them all. Then you can invite "existing testers" again for the new Beta.

Comment: Thanks @combinatorial. Much appreciated.